# How to make diff with redirection from other program output work in make

Tags: bash, makefile, diff

How to make command below work in makefile

```
diff  "./test0.out" < (./myprog < ./textfile.txt)
```

I have an syntax error

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've been searching for solution for some time, but I found nothing similar.

Comment: `/bin/sh` use bash.

Comment: Remove space around `< (`. Should be `<(....)`.

Comment: changed to "bash diff  "./test0.out" < (./myprog < ./textfile.txt)" and nothing

Comment: Command works in terminal but not inside a makefile.

Comment: bash diff  "./test0.out" <(./myprog < ./textfile.txt) still /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: That doesn't let `bash` interpret the command line! What will work is `bash -c 'diff "./test0.out" <(./myprog < ./textfile.txt)'`

Comment: By the way, in this case you can just do `./myprog < ./textfile.txt | diff ./test0.out -` - many Unix utilities accept `-` as a pseudo-filename for standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do process substitution, you have two issues:

- If your `sh` is not `bash` (`ksh`, `zsh`), you can't use process substitution as it is not defined by POSIX
- There must not be any whitespace between `<` and following `(`

Assuming `bash`, do:

```
diff  "./test0.out" <(./myprog < ./textfile.txt)
```

Comment: diff ./test0.out <(./myprog < ./textfile.txt) // works in terminal but not in target in makefile. It's probably the syntax in makefile that does not accept parentheses. I have Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: @residue This needs to be interpreted by `bash`.

Comment: Added `SHELL = /bin/bash` at the beginning of Makefile and changed to `bash diff ./test0.out <(./myprog < ./textfile.txt)` and... `/usr/bin/diff: /usr/bin/diff: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: @residue You are barking the wrong tree here, perhaps you should ask a new question regarding makefile implementation as your initial question is answered already.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I will.